# Setting Up Lua Records for GSLB with PowerDNS in Docker

Tags: domain-name-system, docker, powerdns, zones

I am working with a PowerDNS setup within Docker that currently manages zones through files and responds with A records. My goal is to implement Lua Records for GSLB (Global Server Load Balancing) purposes. Additionally, I am looking to enable API-based management to dynamically update records and handle GSLB configurations.

Below is my current Docker setup. I am encountering difficulties in configuring the system to easily manage new zones and update records via API requests within a containerized environment. Any guidance on how to achieve this setup, especially in terms of integrating Lua Records and API functionality for GSLB, would be greatly appreciated. I am new to docker and powerdns so its being quite troublesome.

How can I seamlessly integrate Lua Records and API management for GSLB within this Dockerized PowerDNS setup?

I am using this dockerfile to do this: https://github.com/pschiffe/docker-pdns/blob/master/docker-compose-mysql.yml

Thanks